# Inserting a datetime with Carbon::now() but add a null attribute Laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm a beginner in `laravel 5.5`. I am trying to insert a current `DateTime` using `Carbon::now()` but the value being added is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

```
$agencyarchive = Agencyarchive::create([
            'agency_id' => $agency->id,
            'date_activated' => Carbon::now()
        ]);
```

My query if I set the agency into active, it would add an archive but the problem is instead its current `datetime`, it adds `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Below are the attributes in my agency archive

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('agency_id')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('date_activated');
        $table->dateTime('date_deactivated')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('agency_id')->references('id')->on('agencies')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you mark those columns as dates in your model:

```
class Agencyarchive extends Model {
  protected $dates = ['date_activated', 'date_deactivated'];
}
```

Comment: I add the protected $dates and all the dates -0001-11-30 00:00:00 but when I remove the protected $dates it revert backs to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: I think you should also change `datetime` into `timestamp` in your schema definition.

Comment: Okay, I now change it into timestamps. However, when I deactivate the agency, I'll update the archive by adding a date now for date_deactivated. `$agency -> status = "Inactive";
            $agency -> save();

            $agencyarchive = Agencyarchive::where('agency_id', $agency->id)
            ->latest('date_activated')
            ->first();
            
            $updarc= Agencyarchive::where('id', $agencyarchive->id)
            ->update([
                'date_deactivated' => Carbon::now()
            ]);` but my date_activated was also update. Why is this?